# How does the OS adjusts itself to the available RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory

In my PC, there is 8GB RAM and runs Windows 10 64-bit OS. In the task manager, I can see that the OS is utilising 50%, that is, approximately 4GB of RAM and the remaining 4GB is free. But, in my friends' computers, which have 4GB RAM, there also I saw that the OS is utilising 50% of RAM. In many computers, there are just 2GB RAM, but it runs fine and there also only 50% memory usage.

So, I am wondering, how does the OS adjusts itself to the available RAM space?

Comment: It doesn't. A sample set of 2 isn't large enough to test your theory.

Comment: Actually, I am not talking about just 2 computers. Please see my edits.

Comment: Quick check of 3 machines here, one using 27GB of 64GB. One 4GB of 24GB & one using 28GB of 32GB. Your conclusions are flawed.

Comment: In low memory situations the disk cache will be unable to fill, and programs will be more aggressively paged out to disk. Windows is designed to adapt to a variety of memory situations. That said 2GB is barely usable and 4GB can be a struggle with modern browsers. It also depends on software loaded and usage patterns for data.